# 301 redirect for new website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an old site www.mysite.com/index.php
and a new site www.mysite.com/cms/index.php

How is the best method to redirect all the page from the old to the new site ?
because people have bookmark old page like mysite.com/contact and i like to redirect it to : mysite/cms/contact_us.php

i know, i can delete the old site, and put the new at root level, i can do a htacces 301, but i sucks at writing rules like : all mysite.com/* to mysite.com/cms

any idea or gui for writing htaccess ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/.*
RewriteRule (^.*$) /cms/$1
```

This will redirect everything that's not within /cms/ there. For example `/contact` will translate to `/cms/contact`.

Comment: amazing... now where i can learn that.. having the answer is fine... knowin to write it is better

Comment: Sorry. [This](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) will probably help you go a long way in writing the rules.