# 301 redirect all pages. Redirection tool or .htaccess

Tags: redirect

I'm looking for a really easy redirect process for my redirection tool. I want to redirect most of my deleted pages to the homepage (over 400) how do i put this in `htaccess` with a good `301` redirect?

Comment: Maybe this could help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378811/301-redirect-for-new-website?rq=1

Comment: Do you have a list of all deleted pages, or are they known by a pattern e.g. /old-content/* ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution, which isn't perfect, is outlined here:

[Redirecting 404 error with .htaccess via 301 for SEO etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363520/redirecting-404-error-with-htaccess)

It redirects all 404 pages to a static page, e.g. your homepage. This means that any page which doesn't exist will be automatically redirected there which achieves what you asked.

If you have a list of known deleted pages, or a pattern by which deleted pages are known then this can be ammended.